# How serve chunk by chunk in PHP without load all in memory

Tags: php, curl

I have a question about chunk by chunk. 
If I am serving a big file to a client, and I am reading chunk by chunk doing the flush/ob_clean() thing... If the client has a slow internet connection, is this big data  going to load in memory? How can I control that? Is possible to know if the client has complete the download of the previous flush so that I can read more and flush more.... Thanks


-This big data is comming from a cURL connection

Answer (score 0):

A good question. Off-hand I'm not sure what happens when the TCP buffer is full. I would expect your webserver component (e.g. Apache) to buffer it up in memory (in which case you're probably SOL at the PHP layer) but I'm only guessing, really.